# Angular 6 ngClass not switching on boolean

Tags: angular

I have a simple problem but can't get through. I have two CSS classes with the just different background image. I want to switch the div background when I clicked on it, and stay that class until I don't switch to another div(menu item).
Here is needed code:

```
.login-switch-button{
    background-image: url("..\..\assets\images\login_button.png"); 
    height: 50px;
    width: 195px;
    float: left;

}
.register-switch-button{
    background-image: url("..\..\assets\images\register_button.png"); 
    height: 50px;
    width: 195px;
    margin: auto;
    float: left;
}

.login-switch-button-active{
    background-image: url("..\..\assets\images\login_button_hover.png"); 
    height: 50px;
    width: 195px;
    float: left;
}

.register-switch-button-active{
    background-image: url("..\..\assets\images\register_button_hover.png"); 
    height: 50px;
    width: 195px;
    float: left;
}
```

Very simple CSS
Here a .ts file

```
 isLoginActive: boolean = true;
  public login_class = {
    "login-switch-button": !this.isLoginActive,
    "login-switch-button-active": this.isLoginActive
  }

  public register_class = {
    "register-switch-button": this.isLoginActive,
    "register-switch-button-active": !this.isLoginActive
  }

  switch_to_login() {
    this.isLoginActive = true;
  }

  switch_to_register() {
    this.isLoginActive = false;
  }
```

And the HTML code

```
  <div (click)="switch_to_login()" [ngClass]="login_class"></div>
  <div  (click)="switch_to_register()" [ngClass]="register_class"></div>
```

At initializing site, the login_button is active, and the background is right for both. But clicking on any of them is changing nothing. The isLoginActive value is changing correctly so the onClick is working fine.
I guess I miss the crucial knowledge about ngClass

Comment: Those objects are only evaluated *once*, when the class is initially defined.

Comment: It does mean that i cannot switching between css classes while using particular site? Can only apply them once during initialization?

Comment: No, you can update it, that's just not what you're doing. If you wrote a setter for isLoginActive (read up on accessors) you could update the objects accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the class based on component property value.

```
<div (click)="switch_to_login()" [ngClass]="isLoginActive ? 'css-class1' : 'css-class2'"></div>
```

If isLoginActive value is true, 'css-class1' will be applied.
If isLoginActive value is false, 'css-class2' will be applied.